# $\int \frac{1}{{1-2x-x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x $ substitution

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I have this integral.
$$\int \frac{1}{{1-2x-x^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
But I am unable to do it right and I just don't know where is the problem in my steps.

My steps:

Complete the square
$$\int \frac{1}{{2-(x+1)^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
$$\frac{1}{2}*\int \frac{1}{{-(x+1)^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
Substitute $$t=x+1$$
$$\frac{1}{2}*\int \frac{1}{{-t^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
$$\frac{1}{2}*\int {{-t^{-2}}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
$$\frac{1}{2}* \frac{-t^{{-1}}}{{-1}}+c  $$
$$ \frac{1}{{2(x+1)}}+c $$

But the result is different.
I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: The denominator is $(x-1)^2$, not $2-(x+1)^2$.

Comment: Isn't $1-2x+x^2=(x-1)^2$?

Comment: Sorry my mistake in heading corrected.

Comment: Your third formula is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do You mean here? $\frac{1}{2}*\int \frac{1}{{-t^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: @JurajJakubov: no, third.

Comment: $2-(x+1)^2$ denotes the difference of $2$ and $(x+1)^2$, not the product of $2$ and $-(x+1)^2$.

Comment: Ou thanks now i understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$1-2x-x^2$$ factors as

$$-(x-a)(x-b)$$ where

$$a,b=1\pm\sqrt2.$$

Then you can decompose

$$\frac{b-a}{(x-a)(x-b)}=\frac1{x-b}-\frac1{x-a}$$ and integrate

$$\log|x-b|-\log|x-a|.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\int\dfrac{1}{1-2x-x^2}\mathrm dx=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2-1}\mathrm dx$$

This is inviting for Partial Fraction Decomposition. Can you proceed?

---

$$\int\dfrac{1}{2-(x+1)^2}\mathrm dx\ne\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{1}{-(x+1)^2}\mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the u-substation $u=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and then do a partial fraction decomposition on the fraction that you will get:
$$
\int\frac{1}{1-2x-x^2}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{2-(x+1)^2}\,dx=\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dx=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}\,du=\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int\frac{1}{(1-u)(1+u)}\,du=
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-u}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+u}\right)\,du=\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\left(-\ln{|1-u|-\ln{|1+u|}}\right)+C=\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\ln{\left|\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right|}+C.
$$

And then do a back-substitution.